# Result exceeded maximum length error

Tags: sql, replace, teradata

The below OREPLACE query is throwing the error.

```
Select cast( OREPLACE (SimpledefinitionQuery , 'gpi','gpiREPLC')  as varchar(40000)) as repl
from SimpleDef0;
```

The return string in the OREPLACE function is set to max of 64000. When I checked the length of column SimpledefinitionQuery, it does not exceed 16000. So I am unable to find why I am getting the error.

Also when I replace 'gpi' with 'gpiRPLC', the query works perfectly. What is going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Whats your Teradata release? `oReplace` usually returns a VARCHAR(8000)` in your case defined as `CHARACTER SET UNICODE`. Now the cast to VARCHAR(40000) exceeds the maximum lenght of a VarChar, 64000 **bytes** = 32000 Unicode **chars**

Comment: TD release is 15.00. Even when I cast it to 32000, it still gives the same error. Here is the query again Select SimpledefinitionQuery,
cast( OREPLACE (SimpledefinitionQuery , 'gpi','gpiREPLC')  as varchar(32000)) as repl,
length(SimpledefinitionQuery),
length(repl) 
from SimpleDef0

Comment: The maximum length of a row is a bit less than 64KB, your CAST almost reaches the limit and adding `SimpledefinitionQuery` exceeds it. How is `SimpledefinitionQuery` defined and why do you want to increase the size?

Comment: The column size of simpledefinitionquery is 32000. Previously we had it 12000 and it worked fine. It is defined as VARCHAR(32000) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC FORMAT 'X(1000)' NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Teradata support page](https://support.teradata.com/knowledge?id=kb_article_view&sys_kb_id=de0609d0db704814278706aaf49619fe), when using `OREPLACE` the returned string also depends on the second and the third arguments

```
OREPLACE (SimpledefinitionQuery , 'gpi','gpiREPLC')
```

> OREPLACE function implicitly converts source string(first argument) to UNICODE when second or third argument is literal(UNICODE) even if the source string is LATIN.

Thus maybe check if the function works if you truncate SimpledefinitionQuery for the first 8000 characters (as suggested in @dnoeth comment it returns Unicode VARCHAR(8000))? Or change the literal type of 2nd and 3rd arguments to Latin as well.